# Manipulating SVG coordinates in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, animation, svg, css-animations

HTML:

```
<svg class="asset-note-icon" viewBox="0 0 100 100">      
    <ellipse cx="38.3" ry="3.5" rx="2.4" cy="57.5"></ellipse>
    <ellipse cx="62" ry="3.5" rx="2.4" cy="57.5"></ellipse>  
    <circle cx="50.1" cy="68.2" r="4.7"></circle>
</svg>
```

CSS:

```
.asset-note-icon{
  width: 120px;
}

.asset-note-icon ellipse,
.asset-note-icon path,
.asset-note-icon circle{
    fill: #636363;
}

.asset-note-icon ellipse{
    animation: blink 50s infinite;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
}

@keyframes blink {
  00.00% { ry: 3.5; cy: 57.5 }     
  10.00% { ry: 3.5 }
  10.10% { ry: 1.0 }
  10.20% { ry: 3.5 }
  10.30% { ry: 1.0 }
  10.40% { ry: 3.5 }
  20.20% { cy: 57.5 }
  20.30% { cy: 50 }
  22.30% { cy: 50 }
  22.40% { cy: 57.5 }
  45.00% { ry: 3.5 }
  45.10% { ry: 1.0 }
  48.10% { ry: 1.5 }
  48.20% { ry: 3.5 }
  99.20% { ry: 3.5 }
  99.30% { ry: 1.0 }
  99.40% { ry: 3.5 }
  100.0% { ry: 3.5; cy: 57.5 }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/m8esm1t3/2/

I've got a little face that animates using SVG and CSS animation. In Chrome the animation works (watch it for about 5 seconds) but it looks like firefox strips away these direct SVG manipulations (rx, cx, cy, etc....)

Is there a way to make this work in firefox as well or is it just not possible in this browser?

Comment: You'd need to rewrite them as SMIL animations.

Comment: Indeed Robert would know more than I but I believe that Chrome is  the only browser (Opera?) currently supporting CSS manipulation of these values/attributes/properties at the point.